# Existe algum erro nestas linhas de comando?

Tags: linux, loop, bash

Estou fazendo comparações entre documentos pelas linhas de comando de Bash e usando um comando de loop. Porém, ocorre um erro com os resultados:

> ```
> ./anibatch.sh: line 38: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 39: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 40: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 41: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 3: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 4: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 5: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 6: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 7: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 8: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 9: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ./anibatch.sh: line 10: ./ANIcalculator: No such file or directory
> ```

com tal informação, eu quero saber se o bash em questão está errado:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *fna; do
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_alginolyticus_DSM_5050_NBRC_15375.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_algorifonticola.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_alvei_DSM_29.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_antarcticus.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_borealis.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_chitinolyticus_NBRC_15660.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_curdlanolyticus_YK9.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_daejeonensis_DSM_15491.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_darwinianus.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_dauci.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_durus_ATCC_35681.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_durus.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_forsythiae_T98.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_glacialis.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_glucanolyticus.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_graminis.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_graminis_RSA19.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_harenae_DSM_16969.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_jilunlii.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_macquariensis_subsp._defensor.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_macquariensis_subsp._macquariensis.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_massiliensis_2301065_DSM_16942.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_odorifer.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_pabuli_NBRC_13638.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_pinihumi_DSM_23905_JCM_16419.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_pini_JCM_16418.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_polymyxa_ATCC_842.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_popilliae_ATCC_14706.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_riograndensis_SBR5.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_sabinae_T27.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_sanguinis_2301083_DSM_16941.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_senegalensis_JC66.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_sonchi_X19-5.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_sp._A9.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_stellifer.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_swuensis.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_taiwanensis_DSM_18679.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_wulumuqiensis.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
./ANIcalculator -genome1fna $file -genome2fna Paenibacillus_zanthoxyli_JH29.fna -outfile genoma_comparacao 
done
```

Comment: Simplemente não existe nenhum ANIcalculator no diretório corrente. Provavelmente está rodando o script no diretório errado.

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque os arquivos não estão no diretório onde você está executando o script. Uma das alternativas é dentro do seu script você entrar na pasta onde se encontra os arquivos ou o arquivo:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    cd <caminho_do_arquivo>
    #restante do script
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que o problema esteja nos locais dos arquivos como o amigo de cima falou. Um exemplo simples que você pode fazer é com esse script de teste. Crie alguns arquivos com a extensão ".tst" de exemplo e veja se ele exibe eles da forma que você precisa.

Como meu exemplo.

```
#!/bin/bash

folders="*.tst"

for i in $folders;do

        ls $i

done
```